# Spring MVC - Set\Populate the content of a JSTL\JSP object with a Japascript object

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i want set the value of a jstl/jsp object by a javascript object in a Spring MVC project, this question is problably already been made , but i'm not find any satisfactory answer on the web, i just started to use Spring MVC so maybe this is a dumb question, in short i want to populate the cotnent of a jstl ModelAtrribute collection with the content of a Array/Object javascript.

These are the classes java i want to use:

**Marker.java**

```
public class Marker  {

private String name;
private String url;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
private String popupContent;

public Marker(){}

public Marker(String name,String url,String latitude,String longitude,String popupContent){
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.popupContent = popupContent;
}
//Getter and setter
}
```

**MarkerList.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MarkerList  implements Serializable {

List<Marker> markers;

public List<Marker> getMarkers() {
    return markers;
}

public void setMarkers(List<Marker> markers) {
    this.markers= markers;
}

}
```

**ControllerMarker.java**

```
@Controller
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public class MarkerController {

//Autowired and setting of all other variables.
//Call the page JSP.
@RequestMapping(value="/map",method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadMap2(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("markerList",markerList);
    return "riconciliazione2/mappa/leafletMap";
}
 @RequestMapping(value="/map3",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String result4(@RequestParam(required=false, value="urlParam")String url, 
                      @ModelAttribute(value="markerList") MarkerList arrayParam

){
    //I want to find a object MarkerList populate with some Marker.
    return "redirect:/map13";
}
```

**Test.jsp**

```
    //some code html....


    <script>
    markerList = [];
    marker = {name:'test',url:'test',latitude:'test',longitude:'test',popupContent:'test'};
    markerList.push(marker);
    <!--How populate the JSTL "markerList" variable??????, i want if possible doing something like this. -->
    var index = 0;
    for(var mark in markerList){
        <c:set var="${marker.name}" scope="session" value="${mark.name.toString()}"/>
        <!-- Other parameter --> 
        <c:out  value="${marker.name}" />
        <!-- Other parameter --> 
        <!-- How can i add the new Marker with the value setted ???-->
    ${markerList}.add(${marker})    
    }
    </script>
    <!-- I want to use the new content of the markerList object with some operation -->
    <c:forEach items="${markerList}" var="idMarker">
    <input id="nameForm" name="nameParam" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${idMarker.name}" />"/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:url var="url" value="/map3" />
<form:form action="${url}" method="post" id="/map3" modelAttribute="markerList">
    <form:input type="hidden" name="markerList" value=${markerList}/>
    <input type="text" name="urlParam" value=""  title="urlParam"/>
    <input type="submit" name="urlFormParam" value="urlForm" />
</form:form>

<c:url var="url" value="/map3" />
<form:form action="${url}" method="post" id="/map3" modelAttribute="markerList">
<form:input type="hidden" name="markerList" value=${markerList}/>
<input type="text" name="urlParam" value=""  title="urlParam"/>
<input type="submit" name="urlFormParam" value="urlForm" />
</form:form>
    //some code html....
```

How can i "send" a javascript object "markerLis"t to the controller ModelAttribute "MarkerList" of Spring MVC?

**NOTE:** I know i can just post the javascript object like a json response and use the "RequestBody" and "ResponseBody" annotation of Spring MVC for receive the json response.

**UPDATE NOTE:** so without any ajax call (i know i hurt myself very much).

i ask this question just for a curiosity purpose.

Ty in advance.

Comment: You can't do this directly as JSP is evaluated on the server side and HTML+JS in user's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an ajax call.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        ...
        //process response code
        ...

    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "URL of spring", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

If you use jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "URL from spring",
    success: function( response ){
        ...
        // Code to process the response
        ...
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

You can generate a form dynamically an submit it. or added to the body of your HTML

```
<script>
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"text");
i.setAttribute('name',"username");

var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

f.appendChild(i);
f.appendChild(s);

//and some more input elements here
//and dont forget to add a submit button

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);

</script>
```

Comment: Ty for the fast response, sorry i forgot to mention on the question  i need to found a solution without any ajax call, i just want to know if exists a way to "cast" a javascript object to a JSTL object  and get the result on a "Model Attribute" of Spring.

Comment: K, this is a solution i can accept, but for be sure there is no way i can set the "username" field directly on the JSTL object "${fullname}" , like this: ${fullname.username} = "new Value"; with javascript code?

Comment: If the fields already exist in the form you can get them with *** document.getElementById("id").value("new value"); *** if you use JQuery *** $( "#id" ),val("new value"); *** http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp